# Grabbing all data values form a web table

Tags: java, selenium, katalon-studio

I need to go through all the table values and grab those into array list (or your some suggested place)

[image]

First-row xpath list

```
    /html[1]/body[1]/div[4]/div[1]/main[1]/div[1]/div[3]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[4]/div[2]/table[1]/tbody[1]/tr[1]/th[1]

    /html[1]/body[1]/div[4]/div[1]/main[1]/div[1]/div[3]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[4]/div[2]/table[1]/tbody[1]/tr[1]/td[1]

    /html[1]/body[1]/div[4]/div[1]/main[1]/div[1]/div[3]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[4]/div[2]/table[1]/tbody[1]/tr[1]/td[2]

.
.
    /html[1]/body[1]/div[4]/div[1]/main[1]/div[1]/div[3]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[4]/div[2]/table[1]/tbody[1]/tr[1]/td[5]
```

2nd row, few xpaths

```
/html[1]/body[1]/div[4]/div[1]/main[1]/div[1]/div[3]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[4]/div[2]/table[1]/tbody[1]/tr[2]/th[1]

/html[1]/body[1]/div[4]/div[1]/main[1]/div[1]/div[3]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[4]/div[2]/table[1]/tbody[1]/tr[2]/td[1]
```

Please provide some Custom keyword logic for capture those values in easy way.

DOM

[image]

Comment: Would you mine giving the url of the page where table is populated? Table looks simple just a tr and td increments.

Comment: https://www.nasdaq.com/market-activity/stocks/aapl/historical

Answer (score 1):

We can start using relative xpath for table's `tbody`then we can use `tagName` method of `By` class for html tag names 'tr' and 'td' to fetch the rows and column elements
then we can save to arrayList as shown below in code.

Note - Closely observe first call to get table start is `findElement` and remaining are `findElements` as we want all elements with tr and td tagname.

```
@Test 
public void testWebTable()  { 
    WebElement simpleTable = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//table[1]/tbody[1]")); 
    // Get all rows 
    List<WebElement> rows = simpleTable.findElements(By.tagName("tr")); 
    List<String> webTableData = new ArrayList<String>(); 

    // Print/Save data from each row 

    for (WebElement row : rows) { 
        List<WebElement> cols = row.findElements(By.tagName("td")); 
        for (WebElement col : cols) {
            webTableData.add(col.getText());
             System.out.print(col.getText() + "\t"); 
           } System.out.println(); 
       }
    }
```

Comment: 1st raw 1st column is "tr[1]" others raw values are td[1],td[2].. . 2nd raw 1st column is "tr[2]" others raw values are td[1],td[2].. in your code , do all cover ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use PHP Simple HTML Dom parser library to parse those table data easily. Check out https://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.io/